# Geting data and tablename from python / oracledb module

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

Hey a have problem with execution query on oracledb in python.

my func:

```
    """Function which connect to oracle DB"""
    connection = oracledb.connect(user='login', password=userpwd, dsn=dsn)
    if connection.is_healthy() == True:
        print("Connection to db successful")
    else:
        print("DB Connection failed...")
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        data = cursor.execute("select * from my_SQL_view")
        for row in data:
            print(row)
```

And now i get tuple with values. But i need dict with key as a table name and value as value. Is it possible to get that kind of dictionary?

i my next function I need to call each value by the key which should be the table name.

Comment: You need to build the dict manually, because the query may contain a lot of tables and you will not be able to identify the source per value. It's also better to use `cursor.fetchmany()` as long as loop over `cursor.execute()` is not a part of PEP-249: [Return values are not defined.](https://peps.python.org/pep-0249/#id20)

Comment: If the results are 2-tuples, you can use `dict()` to turn the results into a dictionary. So you can do this: `dict(cursor)`

Comment: @astentx, its better to use an iterator. If you want to avoid looking at the return value of `execute()` you can simply iterate directly over the cursor -- which is defined in the DB API.

Comment: A side comment: there's no point calling `is_healthy()` immediately after creating a standalone connection - it just adds overhead.  Just check whether `connect()` failed or not.  The `is_healthy()` function is for applications that open connections and let them sit idle for some time.  (Most of these apps might be better with a minimal connection pool, since connection pools can automatically reconnect).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example function that can help you get field by column name. You need to pass to it row and cursor.description:

```
def get_by_name(result, meta, column_name):
  i = 0
  for column in meta:
    if column[0].lower() == column_name.lower():
      return result[i]
    i = i + 1
  return None
```

Then you only need to make following call: `get_by_name(row, cursor.description, 'column_name')`